# aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice - circleci

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, circleci

```html
  name: Deploy to AWS S3
          command: |
            echo aws --version
            if [ "${CURRENT_BRANCH}" == "main" ]
            then
              aws --region ${AWS_REGION} s3 sync ~/repo/build s3://${AWS_BUCKET_PRODUCTION} --delete
            elif [ "${CURRENT_BRANCH}" == "staging" ]
            then
              aws --region ${AWS_REGION} s3 sync ~/repo/build s3://${AWS_BUCKET_STAGING} --delete
            else
              aws --region ${AWS_REGION} s3 sync ~/repo/build s3://${AWS_BUCKET_DEV} --delete
            fi
```

Giving on these commands no idea, I ran command on my window machine seems to run fine, giving problem on CI machine.

Comment: I shared what I thought was necessary to debug the issue, if you need anymore information do ask.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake I had misspelled REIGION as this in environment variables.